# How to calculate onchain Uniswap pool amount by token A or B?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

For example I have 1 UNI Pool A/B which hold 6 A token and 12 B token

If I want for example send 3 A and 6 B how much UNI pool I will receive ?

Is there some function for this for calculate onchain ?

And also how to calculate how much B I need by A input ?